# How to add Custom Sidemenu in Existing Home Page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app Code, i used StackNavigator for Storing Splash Screen, Login Screen, and Home Screen. In that Home Screen i want to add a SideMenu whenever Click a Icon in the Top Right Corner of the Page.

I searched many Drawer Navigator examples. In that examples the side menu is added in Left/Right side of the default header.But in my case, I just create a top bar and in that bar I include Logo, SearchBar Input, Logout Icon,History Icon and Finally the SideMenu Icon.

// Index Page

```
//import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'

import Splash from './src/components/Splash'
import Login from './src/components/Login'
import Home from './src/components/Home'

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: {
        screen: Splash
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    }
},
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
);

const Apps = createAppContainer(MainNavigator)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Apps);
```

HomePage render()

```
<View style={styles.backgroundcontainer}>
                {/* Top Bar */}
                <View style={styles.navBar}>
                    <View style={styles.leftNav}>
                        <Image source={require('../images/logo2.png')} style={{ width: 75, height: 55, borderRadius: 26 }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.middleNav}>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Enter Item to Search..'
                            //placeholderTextColor='rgba(255,255,255, 0.7)'
                            returnKeyType={"next"}
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            value={this.state.search_keyword}
                            onChangeText={(search_keyword) => this.setState({ search_keyword })}
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'center' }} onPress={() => this.getSearchResult(this.state.search_keyword)}>
                            <Icon name="magnify" size={40} color={'#00bfff'} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.rightNav}>
                        {/* <TouchableOpacity style={{ borderBottomColor: 'black' }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Sign In</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity> */}
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.logout()}>
                            <Icon name="logout" size={25} style={styles.navItem} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Icon name="clipboard-outline" size={25} color={'#00bfff'} style={styles.navItem} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Icon name="menu" size={25} color={'#00bfff'} style={styles.navItem} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
</View>
```

package.json

```
react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.4"
```

Expected behaviour is When I click the SideMenu Icon the Sidemenu will open. But I don't have any idea for creating such a Custom Side Menu.

[HomePage] https://i.stack.imgur.com/isSIk.jpg
[Expected Image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3XYx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Create a Drawer Route on top of your navigation routes like this

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
   Home: {
     screen: MainNavigator,
 },
});
const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

and pass your main navigator as a route.

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Splash: {
    screen: Splash
},
Login: {
    screen: Login
},
Home: {
    screen: Home
}
 },
   {
       navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    }
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use react-navigation-drawer for it.

```
//import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer'

import Splash from './src/components/Splash'
import Login from './src/components/Login'
import Home from './src/components/Home'

const HomeStack = createDrawerNavigator({
   Home: {
       screen: Home,
   },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
});

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: {
        screen: Splash
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    Home: HomeStack
},
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    }
);

const Apps = createAppContainer(MainNavigator)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Apps);
```

Then update the menu button for opening the drawer like

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer)}>
      <Icon name="menu" size={25} color={'#00bfff'} style={styles.navItem} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

For more information https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html